# How to run two process at once using kivy

Tags: python-3.x, linux, multithreading, kivy

I'm struggling to simultaneously run my Kivy app alongside a python script that is being locally imported.

**Full python code**

````
import Client # Locall import
import time
from threading import Thread
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):#will manage navigation of windows       
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class Sound(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
    def ipconfig(self,input_ip):
        if len(input_ip) == 13:
            print('Address binded!!')
            Client.host = input_ip #Modify ip adress
        else:
            print('Invalid input_ip')```

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Sound().run()#Kivy run method
    Thread(target = Sound().run()).start()
    time.sleep(10)
    Thread(target = Client.father_main).start()
````

**Where the threading happens**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Sound().run()#Kivy run method
    Thread(target = Sound().run()).start()
    time.sleep(10)
    Thread(target = Client.father_main).start() #Client is locally imported
```

**PROBLEMS**

1.Only the kivy app runs but the father_main function fails to.

2.The only time father_main runs is when I close the kivy application.

3.If i try and remove the 'run()' from Sound(). I get `TypeError: 'Sound' object is not callable` and father_main immediately runs

4.If i only remove the parenthesis from 'run()' so it turns into 'run'. I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Presumably the thread target needs to be a function that will be called, whereas in your example you are starting the app by calling `Sound().run()`. You note that you tried changing this and it broke, but that is the right way to go. Please provide another example where you attempt to do that.

Comment: Also, you might find it easiest to run Kivy in the main thread and use extra threads for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kivy does not encourage the  use of **time.sleep()** and i still have no clue of what exactly your program is but here a solution.

create an `on_start` method (A method that runs when kivy app started) and add start the ipconfig method from there but you're going to start it asynchronously.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


class Sound(App):
    def on_start(self):
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
        async_start = pool.apply_async(self.ip_config, ("value for ip_input here"))
        # do some other things inside the main thread here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Sound().run()
```

Comment: Thanks.Tried your solution and it worked like a charm on it's first try:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the `App` on the main thread. I would suggest something like:

```
def start_father_main(dt):
    Thread(target = Client.father_main).start() #Client is locally imported

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Clock.schedule_once(start_father_main, 10)
    Sound().run()
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should give you the idea.